# Pinning Task Pane in Outlook Add-in

Tags: outlook, add-in, outlook-addin, office-js, office-addins

[I am following this help document](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2017/01/26/pinnable-taskpane-in-outlook-2016/)

To try and figure out how to pin the task pane, I added the Action, as shown in my Manifest here....

```
<ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
  <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
    <Group id="msgReadCmdGroup">
      <Label resid="groupLabel"/>
      <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadPaneButton">
        <Label resid="msgReadPaneButtonLabel"/>
        <Supertip>
          <Title resid="msgReadPaneButtonTitle"/>
          <Description resid="msgReadPaneButtonDesc"/>
        </Supertip>
        <Icon>
          <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon-16"/>
          <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon-32"/>
          <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon-80"/>
        </Icon>
        <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
          <SourceLocation resid="readPaneUrl"/>
          <SupportsPinning>true</SupportsPinning>
        </Action>
      </Control>
    </Group>
  </OfficeTab>
</ExtensionPoint>
```

But, when I go add it into my outlook to test, I get the following error...

`This app can't be installed. The manifest file doesn't conform to the schema definition. The element 'Action' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides' has invalid child element 'SupportsPinning' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides'...`

I have tried searching for the error itself, and cannot find any possible solutions as to why its not working.

EDIT:

I found out I needed to set the version to 1.1, in which I tried:

`<VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">`

And from that, got...

`This app can't be installed. The manifest file doesn't conform to the schema definition. The element 'OfficeApp' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1' has invalid child element 'VersionOverrides' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1'. List of possible elements expected: 'VersionOverrides' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides' as well as any element in namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#'...`

Comment: The error message tells you what's wrong and where the schema is located. Have you tried looking at that schema?

Comment: Yes. According to the documentation, SupportsPinning is a valid child of Action.

Answer (score 2):

To use pinnable taskpane feature you need to set version overrides to version 1.1 See more at [VersionOverrides element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/versionoverrides)

EDIT:

You probably missed the point: "The SupportsPinning element is defined in the VersionOverrides v1.1 schema, so you will need to include a VersionOverrides element both for v1.0 and v1.1."

Please compare you manifest file with the demo manifest you may find over there: [command-demo-manifest.xml](https://github.com/jasonjoh/command-demo/blob/master/command-demo-manifest.xml)

Comment: Well, that gets me one step closer. I edited the OP for the new error...

Comment: Based on your error report and posted part of manifest file, probably nobody would help you. Everything I would suggest would be speculation. If you would like to get some help please post entire manifest file you are trying to use.